How to pass current user information to infrastructure layer in DDD and Onion Architecture?
I am implementing DDD and Onion Architecture in a solution is based on .NET Framework and I will be using Autofac for dependency injection.
The entities tracked with Entity Framework all need audit columns like CreatedOn, CreatedBy, etc. I want to set these inside an override of the SaveChanges method of the DbContext.
CreatedBy should be set to the name of the current user. How do I pass the user name from the presentation layer (ASP.NET MVC) to the override of the SaveChanges method of the DbContext class inside the Infrastructure project?

@PeterB I would like to clarify that my goal is to override the SaveChanges method and set those properties inside the override method so that they are updated from one place.

Ok now I understand. You could add such a method to your ApplicationDbContext class (so with a string userName parameter) but it will not be an actual override because the base class DbContext does not have a method with that signature. What is stopping you from just trying it and putting the results into your question?
